# Angular 2 @Input get's called a lot

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 2 and I'm using some getter's and setter's to communicate between components. I'm running into problems where the getter and setter functions are run a lot of times, even though they don't depend on anything. Am I doing something wrong?

for the getter function I just have this code:

```
 private get SomeData(): string {
        console.log("Getter called");
        return "some string";
 }
```

the setter code is:

```
@Input()
public set SomeData(newData: string) {
    console.log("Setter called");
}
```

The binding is:

```
<child-comp [SomeData]="SomeData"></child-comp>
```

The console is showing Getter called, Setter called, then after that it print some 20 Getter called lines. Why are these called?

Comment: Also this applies to most most/all situations. This offcourse is a simple example, binding to a local variable in the setter also shows the same behavior.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is caused by

```
private get SomeData(): string {
    console.log("Getter called");
    return "some string";
}
```

because it returns a new string instance every time when change detection checks whether the value has changed

If you change the code to

```
private someData:string = "some string";
private get SomeData(): string {
    console.log("Getter called");
    return this.someData;
}
```

then the same string instance will returned every time, Angular recognizes it as unchanged and the setter won't be called unless `someData` has changed.

Comment: But the setter is only called once in my example, so this won't change the fact that the getter keeps getting called. Should I than avoid complicated logic in getters altogether?

Comment: You definitly should avoid complicated ligic in getters and methods bound to in the view.

Comment: I am doing the same thing as your second example with a boolean value declared then returned by the getter.  It is called constantly as well.  Wondering if there are additional issues that can make a getter set off change detection?

Comment: There are several measures to reduce change detection frequency like use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` or `ChangeDetectorRef.detach()`, but the most important thing is that the getter doesn't do real work (CPU intensive) but only returns a value, then it doesn't really matter that it is called often.

Comment: "some string" === "some string", how does angular tell that it's a "new string instance" each time?

Comment: `===` checks idendity as far as I know.